# Wordpress Mediaelement - Youtube Videos Embed Options

Tags: embed, youtube, oembed, iframe

I have a custom field where I define the Youtube Url as a string.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VqHtEF3LPE
```

This then becomes the src in my theme's shortcode:

```
<?php 
    $ysrc = get_field('fl_tube');
    if($ysrc) :
        $poster = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $entry_id ), 'entry-fullwidth', false ); 
        echo do_shortcode( '[x_video_player src="' . $ysrc . '" poster="' . $poster[0] . '" preload="metadata" hide_controls="false" autoplay="false" loop="false" muted="false" no_container="true"]' ); 
?>
```

Wordpress renders this code and produces:

```
<div class="mejs-mediaelement">
    <iframe class="me-plugin" id="me_youtube_0_container" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3VqHtEF3LPE?controls=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com&amp;widgetid=1">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

In order to hide relative videos and info, I need to append to the url in `iframe src`:

```
&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0
```

I cannot add this in my custom field string because then the `iframe src` output displays erroneously as:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3VqHtEF3LPE?rel=0?controls=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com&amp;widgetid=1"
```

Is there a workaround using javascript or a function maybe to append `&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0` to the `iframe src` for all youtube videos embedded on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wordpress function [embed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)

```
<?php 
        global $wp_embed;
        echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode('[embed width="123" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]'); 
?>
```

Comment: This embeds YouTube's `embed` object, not mediaelement video player.